# Change page at XULRunner

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

At my current project we got a website which is shown of a microcontroller at a monitor. I found XULRunner for displaying the page. It is nice, so I can hide all user panels very easy.

The microcontroller got a controller application too. The controller application gets the url which should be displayed from a server. With firefox I can execute "firefox theUrl" and it opens the browser with that url. If the browser is already running, the page opens at the running firefox.

To get that behavior at XULRunner, my main.xul looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  id="display" windowtype="display" title="Display"
  onload="init();" hidechrome="true" zlevel="6">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="cmdline.js" />

  <script><![CDATA[
    function init() {
      var cmdLine = window.arguments[0].QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsICommandLine);
      var content = document.getElementById("content");

      content.setAttribute("src", cmdLine.getArgument(0));
      content.contentWindow.focus();
      window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
    }
  ]]></script>

  <hbox flex="1">
    <browser id="content" flex="1" disablehistory="false"
      src="chrome://commandlineinit/content/default.html" />
  </hbox>
</window>
```

My prefs.js got that content:

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://applicationname/content/main.xul");
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeFeatures", "dialog=no, chrome, centerscreen");
pref("toolkit.singletonWindowType", display
```

And the chrome.manifest:

```
content applicationname content/
```

So, now I can open with **xulrunner application.ini http://www.myPage.de** the page. But when I call it a second, it do nothing.

So I added the commandline handler from that tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/CommandLine

At the method "observe" at *chrome/content/cmdline.js* I added

```
var cmdLine = window.arguments[0].QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsICommandLine);
var content = document.getElementById("content");

content.setAttribute("src", cmdLine.getArgument(0));
content.contentWindow.focus();
```

Now I have 2 problems. At that method, it can't find the element with ID content. So I can't change the url.

The other problem: It calls the observe method only at the first call. I think, the component *components/clh.js* isn't registert.

What did I wrong?